# How to check whether the cell is merged or not in powerbuilder

Tags: excel, powerbuilder

How do i know whether the cell in excel is a merge cell using powerbuilder 12.5?
I'm using the below code but it returned an error "***Name not found accessing external object property selection***".

```
if iole_worksheet.cells(2,3).MergeCells = true then
  messagebox("ee", "merge")
else
  messagebox("ee", "not merge")
end if
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

lb_value = xlsub.Range("D2").MergeCells

if lb_value = True then 
  ...............

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.